# same picture 2 different mean colors in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv, color-space, bgr

I'm working on an opencv 4.5.2 on windows10,  my code is supposed to recognize colors. I met a porblem while scanning a simple picture 20x20 which the colour is defintely red.

[image]

when I run the following snippet

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
const std::string imgpath = "C:\\Users\\nicola\\Desktop\\c++\\qt\\FaceScanner\\FaceScanner\\images\\";

int main()
{
    cv::Mat origin = cv::imread(imgpath+"square_red.jpg");
    cv::Mat hsv;
    cv::cvtColor(origin, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    cv::Scalar color = cv::mean(hsv);
    std::cout << "HSV: " << color[0] << " " << color[1] << " " << color[2] << "\n";
    color = cv::mean(origin);
    std::cout << "BGR: " << color[0] << " " << color[1] << " " << color[2] << "\n";
}
```

the output I'm getting is

```
HSV: 88.4 251.532 238.768
BGR: 8.96 3.52 238.768
```

The problem is that this 2 colors are different because hsv(88, 251, 238) is a kind of green while bgr(8, 3, 238) is the red I'm expecting. To process the color I need it in the hsv color space. Can anybody fiugre this out? thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with `cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL`? And are you sure you don't need `cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL` instead? You can find the full list of color conversion codes [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html).

Comment: It depends on what HSV range you are working on. OpenCV defines the `Hue` range in `[0,180)` to store the Hue values in a `uint8`. However, the "theoretical" Hue range is defined as `[0, 360]`. The `HSV` you are printing lies in OpenCV's "reduced" range. By using the color code `BGR2HSV_FULL` you are using the full range. So, both values should map the same color, it just depends on what range you are using. Additional tip: You are processing a  `jpeg `. This image format is lossy and will modify the values of your pixels due to compression. Use `png`  to create lossless images.

Comment: So you re expecting hsv output similar to bgr output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just ask for the mean of *hue angles*.

The arithmetic mean doesn't make sense on angles. Not in this case.

Your picture is red. Red has a hue angle of around 0. Add some noise, because JPEG and whatnot. That gets you values *around* 0, with some small positive and some small negative values... except, the negative ones won't be negative after `cvtColor`, they'll be around 359! 359 because 360 degrees in a circle. But wait! OpenCV returns hue angles mapped to `0 .. 179` because 359 doesn't fit in an `uint8`. So you have some values around 0 and some around 179.

Then you're averaging some 0 and some 179... and you get your `88.4`, which is close to 90, which makes mathematical sense, but the value (180 degrees, green-blue) is complete nonsense, as you noticed.

**Instead,** do the averaging in RGB/BGR or YUV space. There it makes sense, i.e. is well defined.

Once you have the mean in a color space where it can be calculated, then you can use `cvtColor` to convert it. I'm not terribly familiar with the C++ API of OpenCV, so if `cvtColor` doesn't eat Scalars as is, stick the Scalar into a Mat.